# How can I autostart a headless Kodi on Lubuntu?

Tags: headless, intel-nuc, kodi

I am running Kodi on Lubuntu (Ubuntu) 20.10 on an Intel NUC, but I think this works in general. I wanted the system to auto-login and auto-start into Kodi.

I installed Lubuntu on a fresh system and just issued an `apt-get install kodi`. (you can also use `apt install kodi`, if you are more modern than me)

- System: Linux NUC2 5.8.0-53-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 07:46:32
  UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Kodi: 18.8: Debian package version: 2:18.8+dfsg1-2 Media Center Kodi from Debian

My default window system is LXQt, successor of LXDE.

I wonder what the best way is to do this, and if this also works on other not-dedicated Kodi machines like Raspberry Pi, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put your answer inside the question. Use the **Answer Your Own Question** button below to answer your question. Then you can accept your answer as the correct answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 3):

Took me 2 hours to search and figure out, I think this can help others to do this in 10 minutes.

**Step 1:**
Create a user with "auto login". In my case, I had created a user "start" that automagically logs in without a password. How? In LXQt: go to Start --> Preferences --> LXQ Settings --> Users and Groups. Create that user.

You can use command line if you prefer, and adjust it like this:
`vi /etc/sddm.conf`
You can also put a user here with a password, that user will also auto-login

**Step 2: Auto-start Kodi**
In the home directory of that user (in my case "start"), copy the file /usr/share/applications/kodi.desktop to .config/autostart

Log in as "start"

```
mkdir /home/start/.config/autostart
cd /home/start/.config/autostart
cp /usr/share/applications/kodi.desktop ./
```

(I am skipping the ~/ notation to make it easier for beginners)

Hint: Rename `/usr/share/applications/kodi.desktop` to `kodi.desktop.txt` and it will reboot into LXQt again in stead of Kodi.

**General hint 1:**
Turn off or modify the screensaver of your windowing system, since it may override Kodi. In LXQt for example: In LXQt --> Preferences --> LXQt Settings --> Screen Saver

**General hint 2:**
Default sound output in my case was analog (the mini-jack port), change it to HDMI in LXQt --> Sound & Video --> PulseAdio Volume Control --> tab 'configuration' --> "Digital Stereo Output". After reboot, it returns every time to analog audio, will figure that out later.